# Create numpy array from multi index pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas series like below:

```
Year  Month
2016  09        41
      10        76
      11        54
      12       271
2017  01        88
      02        48
      03        54
      04        61
      05       156
      06        43
      07        57
      08        43
      09        69
      10        67
      11        99
      12       106
2018  01        34
Name: CustomerId, dtype: int64
```

I just want to create a numpy array which all years match with months and values. Like this:

```
2016  01    0
2016  02    0
.
.
.
2016  09   41
2016  10   76
.
.
.
2018  01   34
2018  02    0
.
.
.
```

How can I do this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unstack` + `stack`

```
S.unstack().stack(dropna=False).fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[591]: 
Year  Month
2016  1          0
      2          0
      3          0
      4          0
      5          0
      6          0
      7          0
      8          0
      9         41
      10        76
      11        54
      12       271
2017  1         88
      2         48
      3         54
      4         61
      5        156
      6         43
      7         57
      8         43
      9         69
      10        67
      11        99
      12       106
dtype: int32
```

Comment: @yigitozmen yep :-)